# How to automate Solver with a Worksheet Change event?

Tags: excel, vba, solver, worksheet-function

I am working on a sales projection model based on a sigmoid curve. As part of the model, I hope to fit the curve to available historical data, using the sum of squared differences (SUM) between the projection and the historical. The only variable for the curve is its steepness, which I am using Solver to solve for the minimum of SUM.

I hope to make this model more dynamic by allowing users to update the historical figures (highlighted in green) once they become available. But instead of needing to run Solver every time the historical figures are updated, is it possible to automate this by integrating a Worksheet Change event for VBA? I am quite new to VBA, so I'm not too sure how to include a function like Solver into the event.

Attached are screenshots of the model and the parameters for Solver:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnO0L.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4zeq.jpg

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you can write a Sub to run Solver (maybe start by recording a macro if you're not sure how to do that) then you can call that Sub from the Change event.

Comment: Seen q&a on here with Solver used in vba.

Comment: ... try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba+solver).